# Format Datetime2 object

Tags: php, azure

I have a datetime2 which looks like this:

```
2012-10-06 22:00:00.0000000
```

(using php for Microsofts Azure) and I dont know how to format it to something like:

```
October 06, 2012 at 22:00
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I see this question almost every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime()`:

```
echo date('F d, Y \a\t H:i', strtotime('2012-10-06 22:00:00.0000000'));
// October 06, 2012 at 22:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Date()](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentdate="2012-10-06 22:00:00.0000000";
$timestamp=strtotime($currentdate);
$newdate=date("F d Y g:i",$timestamp);
echo $newdate;
```